# VMware player suspends on screensaver

Tags: vmware-player

I have this problem with my VMWare player. When my host operating system either goes into screen saver mode or I lock the work station with Windows Key + L. VMWare player seems to suspend the virtual machine and everything it is doing is paused. When I resume or exit the screen saver the virtual machine looks like its resuming everything again, though it was not working as a background task.

Is there any way to stop this behaviour with VMWare player and keep it running in the background even when the screen saver or the work station is locked?

Version of VMWare is:
3.0.0 build-203739

Answer (score 2):

i'd suggest to go in your guest operating system and change the screensaver and power settings (disable them completely from guest). this is the first thing i do after installing a windows box vm.